# Parsing nested objects with Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I am using Robospice + Retrofit + Jackson. I have not plain class which has another class object as a field. I need to parse json and create class with field.
Here is my class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class User implements UserInformationProvider {
    @JsonProperty("customer_id")
    public int id;
    @JsonProperty("firstname")
    public String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("lastname")
    public String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String email;
    @JsonProperty("telephone")
    public String phone;
    @JsonProperty("token_api")
    public String token;
    @JsonProperty("token_expire")
    public int tokenExpireTime;
    public UserPreferences userPreferences;
    @Override
    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUserIconUrl() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And preferences class

```
public class UserPreferences {
    public boolean offersNotifications;
    public boolean statusChangedNotifications;
    public boolean subscriptionNotifications;
    @JsonProperty("new_offers")
    public boolean newOffersNotify;
    @JsonProperty("order_status_changed")
    public boolean orderStatusChangedNotify;
    @JsonProperty("hot_offers")
    public boolean hotOffersNotify;
}
```

Request that I need to parse into POJO.

```
{
    "customer_id": 84,
    "token_api": "ef5d7d2cd5dfa27a",
    "token_expire_unix": "1435113663",
    "preferences": {
        "new_offers": "1",
        "order_status_changed": "1",
        "hot_offers": "1"
    }
}
```

Please help, how can I do this using Jackson. I would be very grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem lies inside of `UserPreferences`. Right now your code is attempting to deserialize `"1"` as a `boolean`. Java will not do this translation for you, so you will need to create a custom deserializer and apply it to the fields with numeric booleans.

#### Create a Custom Deserializer

A deserializer allows you to specify a class and apply custom operations to how it is created from JSON:

```
public class NumericBooleanDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        int intValue = p.getValueAsInt();
        switch (intValue) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            case 1:
                return Boolean.FALSE;
            default:
                // throw exception or fail silently
        }
        return null; // can throw an exception if failure is desired
    }
}
```

#### Apply Custom Deserialization to Fields

Since you probably don't want to register this on your `ObjectMapper` and apply it to *all* deserialization, you can use the `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. Your `UserPreferences` class will end up looking something like this:

```
public class UserPreferences {
    public boolean offersNotifications;
    public boolean statusChangedNotifications;
    public boolean subscriptionNotifications;

    @JsonProperty("new_offers")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    public boolean newOffersNotify;

    @JsonProperty("order_status_changed")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    public boolean orderStatusChangedNotify;

    @JsonProperty("hot_offers")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = NumericBooleanDeserializer.class)
    public boolean hotOffersNotify;
}
```

#### Make Sure `@JsonProperty` Matches JSON Keys

Since your JSON has `"preferences"` and the name of your Java property is `userPreferences` you will need to slap a `@JsonProperty("preferences")` on the property inside of `User`